# Why does firebug change the behavior of a website when debugging?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I'm working on a website that uses Extjs and I'm debugging using firebug in Firefox. I've noticed that when I stop at a breakpoint in firebug and then start execution again a few seconds later sometimes things that were happening on the website stop happening. For example if clicking a button causes A to happen which causes B which causes C and my breakpoint is on A then B and C are liable to not happen at all if I stop at the breakpoint.

My current best guess is that when things like this happen (this happens a lot in a lot of different scenarios) its because actions have been set to timeout and they do while I'm stopped at the breakpoint.

Why does this happen?

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Note the scientific tenet that measuring a phenomena will affect the outcome in some way

Comment: Does the same thing happen with Safari or Chrome in the Web Inspector?

Answer (score 0):

one thing I can think of is asynchronous events and onComplete handlers, such as from animations/tweening which the breakpoint may or may not actually pause. Or if there's a background XHR request, i'm not sure how that's handled by a breakpoint.

I think @kevinDTimm means the observer effect from physics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28physics%29